# How do I query an optional column with a secondary index using phantom?

Tags: phantom-dsl

I have a secondary index on an optional column:

```
class Sessions extends CassandraTable[ConcreteSessions, Session] {
  object matchId extends LongColumn(this) with PartitionKey[Long]
  object userId extends OptionalLongColumn(this) with Index[Option[Long]]
  ...
}
```

However, the `indexedToQueryColumn` implicit conversion is not available for optional columns, so this does not compile:

```
def getByUserId(userId: Long): Future[Seq[Session]] = {
  select.where(_.userId eqs userId).fetch()
}
```

Neither does this:

```
select.where(_.userId eqs Some(userId)).fetch()
```

Or changing the type of the index:

```
object userId extends OptionalLongColumn(this) with Index[Long]
```

Is there a way to perform such a query using phantom?

I know that I could denormalize, but it would involve some very messy housekeeping and triple our (substantial) data size. The query usually returns only a handful of results, so I'd be willing to use a secondary index in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You could not use optional fields in order to query things in phantom.

Long detailed answer:

But, if you really want to work with secondary optional columns, you should declare your entity field as Option but your phantom representation should not be an option in order to query.

```
object userId extends LongColumn(this) with Index[Long]
```

In the fromRow(r: Row) you can create your object like this:

```
Sessions(matchId(r), Some(userId(r)))
```

Then in the service part you could do the following:

```
.value(_.userId, t.userId.getOrElse(0))
```

You also have a better way to do that. You could duplicate the table, making a new kind of query like sessions_by_user_id where in this table your user_id would be the primary key and the match_id the clustering key.

Since user_id is optional, you would end with a table that contains only valid user ids, which is easy and fast to lookup.

Cassandra relies on queries, so use it in your favor.

Take a look up on my github project that helps you get up with multiple queries in the same table.

https://github.com/iamthiago/cassandra-phantom

Comment: Thanks! I ended up extending phantom to support this. I've since run load tests, and it turns out that I will have to denormalize after all, otherwise the performance just is not good enough.